# How to fix Bash commands not working/found

Tags: bash, terminal, command-line-arguments, git-bash, prompt

I am trying to use bash commands but none of them works as they are not recognized.
I don't know if it is a path issue or what is going on. I tried several things.

Is there any way to make a fresh install of the bash terminal, paths or environment variables? I guess it is a problem related to one of those things.

Anything I type, I get the following error:

"bash: curl: command not found"

`$sudo apt update`

bash: curl: command not found

`$curl`

bash: curl: command not found

`$sudo apt install curl`

bash: curl: command not found

`$printenv`

bash: curl: command not found

Comment: A clean install almost certainly will not help at all; the problem is not with Bash itself. _Probably_ you have an error in one of your personal shell startup files, but your question contains no useful information to help us troubleshoot your `PATH`. What's the output of `echo "$PATH"` and where is `curl` installed?

Comment: For a radical reset, you could remove (or, less drastically, move to a subdirectory) all your shell startup files. `cd; mkdir away; mv .profile .bash* away/` but then to take it from there you probably want to recreate them with useful settings you scavenge out of the files you moved away.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's complaining about `curl` *regardless of the command you use* possibly means something has changed the possible vectors for executing code at time of command entry, and that it's trying to execute `curl` as part of that.

One vector is the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable. That variable is used to run an arbitrary command before displaying a prompt for every command entry (for example, I've used it for append-saving and restoring shell history so that history is available across multiple interactive shells - normally it only loads on shell start-up and saves on exit).

Another vector is the `PS1` environment variable (thanks to user `tripleee` for pointing this out in a comment). You could see this in action were you to enter `PS1="$(uname): " in a command prompt. But ***don't*** do that yet, at least until you've investigated as per below.

If either of those is the case, you can use `echo "pc='${PROMPT_COMMAND}' ps1='${PS1}'"` to find out.

Then you'll either need to fix the variable or figure out why `curl` is not able to run.

Comment: Nice hypothesis. It could also be in the prompt itself (`PS1`).

Comment: @tripleee: good point, I forgot about that one. Added it to the answer as something else to check.

Comment: Apologies, @triple, I should have checked the spelling first, including in this comment :-) And thanks also for fixing my code fart with the (non-)expansion.